# compare mustache generated string in php

Tags: php, javascript, mustache, icanhaz.js

If i compare a mustache generated variable with the actual string it shows weird result.

```
<?php
$username = {{userName}};
echo $username; // john

 //if i compare with the string it returns false
if ($username == 'john') //return false

//if i print strlen($username) it returns 14 but it should return 4

?>
```

how to convert it to regular string so i can compare it with other string in php? any help?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in to trim http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

It looks like mustache adds some whitespace.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump()` it? If it is an object it should have `__toString()` or `toString()` method to cast it to a string. If it is an object you can try to `var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($username)));` to see all the available methods.

Comment: What library do you use for mustache?

Comment: It is a string. I'm using mustache.js with icanhaz.js

Answer (score 0):

That's because those "mustache" variables aren't PHP variables - they originated from Javascript.

http://icanhazjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough context to actually answer the question, but from the symptoms I'd say your string is `&quot;john&quot;`.

You're using escaped output (`{{ foo }}`) instead of unescaped (`{{{ foo }}}`) which is almost certainly wrong for PHP rather than HTML output. I don't know about icanhaz.js, but in many Mustache implementations you can swap out the escaper for something more relevant. In this case, you probably want an escaper which does the equivalent to `var_export()` in PHP.